# How to use Rack::URLMap with Rack::Cascade to mount Resque in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, resque

I have been running a rails 2.3 app with a rackup config.ru file to load some grape API middleware.

I recently have a need to run a resque server.

My config.ru is set up like this.

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'

my_app = Rack::Builder.new do
 use Rails::Rack::LogTailer #optional
 use Rails::Rack::Static # optional
 run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
end



Resque::Server.class_eval do
  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |user, password|
    begin
      if user == "admin" and password == "bandana"
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end 
  end

end

run Rack::URLMap.new([
  "/" => my_app,
  "/resque" => Resque::Server.new
])

run Rack::Cascade.new([
  GrapeAPI_entry_1,
  GrapeAPI_entry_2,
  my_app
])
```

This doesn't give me the desired effect and I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

I actually found the answer. It turned out that redis was not running, and yes, you can use cascade with map

My final config.ru looks like this.

```
re File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'
require 'resque/server'

my_app = Rack::Builder.new do
 use Rails::Rack::LogTailer #optional
 use Rails::Rack::Static # optional
 run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
end

Resque::Server.class_eval do
  use Rack::Auth::Basic do |user, password|
    begin
      if user == "admin" and password == "bandana"
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end 
  end

end



app = Rack::Builder.new {
  use Rails::Rack::Static

  map "/resque" do
    run Resque::Server
  end

  map "/" do
    run my_app
  end
}.to_app

run Rack::Cascade.new([
  Grape_API_1,
  Grape_API_2,
  my_app
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently added similar access to resque on one of my rails servers. It works great -- here is how I did it:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
require 'resque/server'

run Rack::URLMap.new \
  "/"       => MyApp::Application,
  "/resque" => Resque::Server.new
```

My app is based on rails 3.2, however. I'm not sure what the difference is in the rack version you're running.

Are you requiring the resque server code?